# Apache2 - Forward a value from URL param OR cookie, whichever is present

Tags: apache-2.2, cookies, rewritecond, requestheader

I managed to use apache to strip off a url param and stuff it in a header to be passed on to another server. [See this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/413428/use-apache-to-strip-off-a-url-param-and-add-it-as-a-custom-http-header-on-a-redi) for reference.

Now I would like to add to this by getting the value for the header from a cookie if it's not present in the URL. Here's what I tried:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  RewriteEngine On

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)memberUuid=(.*)$
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [CO=memberUuid:%2:localhost,E=memberUuid:%2,P]

  RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} memberUuid=(.*)
  RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ http://127.0.0.1:9000/$1 [E=memberUuid:%2,P]

  ProxyPreserveHost On
  ProxyPass /excluded !
  ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:9000/
  ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:9000/

  Header add iv-user "%{memberUuid}e"
  RequestHeader set iv-user "%{memberUuid}e"
</VirtualHost>
```

This still works if the `memberUuid` is in the URL, but it doesn't seem to work with the cookie. I have the `memberUuid` cookie in my browser, but if I leave the URL param off, the `iv-user` header has an empty value.

I also tried `([^;]+)` for my regular expression, as recommended in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6021552/check-cookie-and-redirect-with-apache).

I'm sure that my mistake has a lot to do with me being a complete apache idiot. I'm a complete noob and not embarrassed to say it. Enlighten me please!

**Edit**

I've updated my virtual host so that apache will set the `memberUuid` cookie in the user's browser if it comes from the query string. That way, I can be sure that the cookie is present on the next request (I was previously having the destination server do this).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might not be the only issue (I've never done cookie matching in mod_rewrite before); but  I think it's because your backreference for the `RewriteRule` is still `%2`. You only have one parenthesised match in the previous `RewriteCond`, so it expands to nothing. Try `[E=memberUuid:%1,P]`

Comment: Ok, that should have been a no-brainer.  That's what I get for working late!